# Javascript IE conflict

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

the following javascript code is working in FF and Chrome but in an any versions of IE. There does not appear to be any obvious errors I can find.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// hide/expose  search_by2 to/from dates 
function hide_search_by2(that){
    selected_value = that.options[that.selectedIndex].value;

    if(selected_value == 'vehicles_sales.nodate'){
        document.getElementById("search_by2_from_row").hidden=true;
        document.getElementById("search_by2_to_row").hidden=true;  
    } else {
        document.getElementById("search_by2_from_row").hidden=false;
        document.getElementById("search_by2_to_row").hidden=false;  
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what does selected_value contain in IE?

Comment: Hi, it returned "vehicles_sales.nodate"

Comment: And does #search_by2_from_row have an attribute called hidden?

Comment: Hi, yes it does have an inherited style, because it's in a table that is hidden by default. Is this where the conflict originates?

Comment: If the parent node is hidden its children probably are, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is hidden?

Set display to none if you want to hide an element.

**hide**

```
document.getElementById("search_by2_from_row").style.display = "none";
```

**show**

```
document.getElementById("search_by2_from_row").style.display = "inline";  //or "block"
```

or visibility

**hide**

```
document.getElementById("search_by2_from_row").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

**show**

```
document.getElementById("search_by2_from_row").style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: display is different from hidden
however early IE don't seem to like 'hidden'

Comment: There's no such thing as `display:hidden`. However `display:none` is valid.

Comment: Hi, this worked when I used display:none as per slebetman suggestion. Please update your answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: Must of been the beer that made me type hidden. :)